# Overwrite some rows in pandas dataframe with ones from another dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, df1.

I want  to overwrite its values with values in df2, where the index and column name match.

I've found a few answers on this site, but nothing that quite does what I want.

df1

```
   A   B   C
0  33  44  54
1  11  32   54
2  43  55  12
3  43  23  34

df2
   A
0  5555
```

output

```
   A   B   C
0  5555  44  54
1  11  32   54
2  43  55  12
3  43  23  34
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with convert to integer if necessary:

```
df = df2.combine_first(df1).astype(int)
print (df)
      A   B   C
0  5555  44  54
1    11  32  54
2    43  55  12
3    43  23  34
```

If need check intersection index and columns between both `DataFrame`s:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'A':[5555, 2222],
                   'D':[3333, 4444]},index=[0, 10])

idx = df2.index.intersection(df1.index)
cols = df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)

df = df2.loc[idx, cols].combine_first(df1).astype(int)
print (df)
      A   B   C
0  5555  44  54
1    11  32  54
2    43  55  12
3    43  23  34
```